# Share button (feed) with Direct URL opens entire facebook page instead on popup

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am implementing a share button on my facebook app ( I don't wanna use Like ) And i am using this url for it :

```
  http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=123050457758183&
  link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
  picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=Reference%20Documentation&
  description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&
  redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response&
  display=popup
```

I got it from [This Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) and [Display Modes](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#display)

Now when i do press the link, the Facebook dialogs runs in full-page mode with a Facebook header and footer instead of a "popup".

Anyone knows how can I can get teh Facebook dialog to display in a popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now when i do press the link, the Facebook dialogs runs in full-page mode with a Facebook header and footer instead of a "popup".

It clearly states there,

> *“popup: For use in a browser popup no bigger than 400px by 580px.”*

All this does is *format* the dialog in a way that it will fit into a small window – it does nothing about how/where the URL is opened (and how could it, an URL alone never decides *where* it gets opened).

> Anyone knows how can I can get teh Facebook dialog to display in a popup?

By opening the URL in a popup yourself. (Of course you have to take care of closing it afterwards and maybe reloading the parent window yourself, too.)

Or you just use `FB.login`method out of the JS SDK, which handles all that stuff nicely for you.

Comment: Thanks CBroe for clarifying...  makes sense.  I decided to use the FB.ui call with the "display: popup" parameter.  Question throught, when I hit cancel or submit, the popup that is instantiated does not go away.  Instead, the url referenced in the redirect_uri paramter is rendered in the popup.  The documentation states that the popup should be dismissed.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I have not seen an example that combines the fb.login and fb.ui dialogs.  Examples call the fb.ui directly, including the Facebook documentation and sample site.  Is the idea to call fb.login and in the successful callback call fb.ui?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I confused your sharing-problem with login. How exactly are you using FB.ui?

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me CBroe.  I created a new Stack Overflow item.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377274/facebook-feeds-popup-dialog-does-not-close