# Facebook Feeds Popup Dialog Does Not Close

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Using the FB.ui to publish a feed with parameter display:popup.  When a user selects the "Cancel" or after "Share", the web site specified in the 'redirect_uri' parameter is displayed within the popup.  The Facebook documentation states that the popup dialog should be dismissed when the buttons are cancelled.

Here is my code.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>

<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: my APP ID, status: true, cookie: true,
            xfbml: false, channelUrl: 'MY URL/fb-channel.html'
        });
    };

function fbShare(title, fbSiteUrl, fbThumbnailUrl, fbSiteDescription) {
    var publish = {
        method: 'feed',
        name: title,
        caption: 'MY CAPTION',
        description: fbSiteDescription,
        picture: fbThumbnailUrl,
        link: fbSiteUrl,
        redirect_uri: 'MY WEB SITE URL',
        actions: [
            { name: 'MY WEB SITE Name', link: 'MY WEB SITE URL' }
        ],
        display: 'popup'
    };

    function callback(response) {
    }

    FB.ui(publish, callback);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you specify a `redirect_uri` at all? This i generally not necessary when using FB.ui.

Comment: If I do not specify redirect_uri I get an error in the popup window.  I don't recall what it is at the moment.  I did some reading and it appears that FB made the redirect_uri required.

Comment: CBroe - You were correct.  Different behaviors running local vs deployed tripped me up.